# Possible solutions to creating a QR code with 600 characters?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, barcode-scanner, scanning

I have a 600 character string that I want to convert into a QR code, but apparently there is a limitation of some sort. I used: http://goqr.me/

With the following text:

> 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

It works sometimes when scanning.

- Is there a better js library I can use to render the QR code properly?
- What other improvements can I do to get this to scan more reliably?

Comment: You could shorten the string, either apply some compression or if you have access to the internet you could use an urlshortener or store the string in a database and only send the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia article on QR Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage), the limit is character set dependent. For alphanumeric (digits, UPPER CASE letters, limited other characters) it is 4,296 characters and for 8-bit binary 2,953 characters. Your sample looks like a hexadecimal encoding of binary data. If it is really binary data then you could consider it as half-as-many (~ 300) characters binary. Or leave it as-is with a full ~ 600 characters binary. Or you could treat it as alphanumeric for a smaller encoding but have to deal with UPPER/lower case. In any case, it should fit just fine.

Take a look at [jquery.qrcode.js](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/jquery-qrcode/) I did a quick test with your text and got:

[image: sample QR code]

and it scanned fine with my Android phone.

Comment: nope my phone doesnt scan it. anyone else try? i have a moto z2 play

Comment: I suspect the problem is the high resolution, which is based on a combination of the number of characters and the character set. I'm not sure (took a quick look and didn't figure it out yet) how to set that in jquery.qrcode.js. Key question: Does it matter upper vs. lower case for this application?